# The number of solutions of $x^m \equiv 1 \bmod n$, $n$ not prime

Tags: number-theory

How can I find the number of solutions for the equation $x^{m} \equiv 1 \bmod n$ where $m, n \geq 1$ and $n$ is **not** prime? I guess it would be $\varphi (n)$ (the Euler's totient function), but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is $m$ fixed, or is that variable?

Comment: Yeah it's not clear what letters are variable and which letters are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to add is that you want the number of such $x$ modulo $n$ and not $m$. So you just need to show that for all $x$ relatively prime to $n$, there exists $m$ such that $x^m\equiv1\pmod n$. This can be proven just by the fact that the sequence $x, x^2, x^3, x^4,...$ eventually repeats modulo $n$. This is obvious as there are infinite terms in this sequence and only finite residue classes.

So we have $x^j\equiv x^k\pmod n$ for $j<k$ or equivalently, $k=j+r$ for some positive integer $r$. We have that $n|x^k-x^j=x^j(x^r-1)$. As $x^j$ is relatively prime to $r$, we get $n|x^r-1$ or $x^r\equiv1\pmod n$. Thus, there must be a solution for every choice of $x$ relatively prime to $n$.